# Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.ezcompras.model.Lojas

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get a child values, I already get some values in another activities and I had no problem. Now I create a new listener in my new activity and I don't get values. I can find but I can't pass to my object; I will put some code to try explain what I'm saying.

I whant this in red(Edited)
(https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/375765058992603136/630091075226173479/unknown.png)

Error

(https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/375765058992603136/628991006217469953/unknown.png)

I'm saving values on object (this is my register activity)

```
 private void salvarComerciantePt2() { //save store object

    if (dados != null && localizacao != null) {
        String categoria = spinnerCategoria.getSelectedItem().toString();//geting a category
        if(categoria != null){
                empresa.setNomeProprietario((String) dados.get("nomeProprietario"));
                empresa.setTelefone((String) dados.get("telefone"));
                empresa.setEmail((String) dados.get("email"));
                empresa.setCpf((String) dados.get("cpf"));
                empresa.setCnpj((String) dados.get("cnpj"));
                empresa.setSenha((String) dados.get("senha"));
                empresa.setLocalizacao(localizacao);
                empresa.setCategoria(categoria);
                empresa.setNomeEmpresa(inputNomeEmpresa.getText().toString());
                criaUsuarioFirebase(empresa.getEmail(), empresa.getSenha());// create firebase user
        }




    }
}
```

Here I'm trying to get values from firebase (I want to get child localizacao)

Debug after this, my code crashes

(https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/375765058992603136/629010455473684493/unknown.png)

```
private void recuperarLocalizacao(){

    DatabaseReference lojaRef = mDatabase
            .child("empresa")
            .child(idLoja) //idStore
            .child("localizacao");

    lojaRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                  local =  ds.getValue(Localizacao.class); // try to pass values to my Localizacao.java
                }

          //  Double latitude = local.getLatitude();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Here I'm saving values on Localizacao.java (this is my register activity)

```
 private void autoComplete() {
    AutocompleteSupportFragment autocompleteFragment = (AutocompleteSupportFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.autocomplete_fragment);

    autocompleteFragment.setPlaceFields(Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME, Place.Field.LAT_LNG));

    autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
            // TODO: Get info about the selected place.
            Log.i("PlaceCerto", "Place: " + place.getName() + ", " + place.getId());
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(CadastroPt2Activity.this, Locale.getDefault());
            try {
                List<Address> listaEnderecos = geocoder.getFromLocationName(place.getName(), 1);
                if(listaEnderecos != null && listaEnderecos.size() >0){
                    Address address = listaEnderecos.get(0);
                    localizacao.setLatitude(place.getLatLng().latitude); // save latitude
                    localizacao.setLongitude(place.getLatLng().longitude); // save longitude
                    salvaLocal(address);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Status status) {
            // TODO: Handle the error.
            Log.i("PlaceErrado", "An error occurred: " + status);
        }
    });
}

private void salvaLocal(Address address){// save place

    localizacao.setEstado(address.getAdminArea());
    localizacao.setCidade(address.getCountryName());
    localizacao.setCep(address.getPostalCode());
    localizacao.setBairro(address.getSubLocality());
    localizacao.setRua(address.getThoroughfare());
    localizacao.setNumero(address.getFeatureName());
}
```

Localizacao.java

```
package com.example.ezcompras.model;
```

public class Localizacao {

```
private String estado;
private String cidade;
private String bairro;
private String rua;
private String numero;
private String cep;
private Double latitude;
private Double longitude;

public Localizacao() {
}

public String getEstado() {
    return estado;
}

public void setEstado(String estado) {
    this.estado = estado;
}

public String getCidade() {
    return cidade;
}

public void setCidade(String cidade) {
    this.cidade = cidade;
}

public String getBairro() {
    return bairro;
}

public void setBairro(String bairro) {
    this.bairro = bairro;
}

public String getRua() {
    return rua;
}

public void setRua(String rua) {
    this.rua = rua;
}

public String getNumero() {
    return numero;
}

public void setNumero(String numero) {
    this.numero = numero;
}

public String getCep() {
    return cep;
}

public void setCep(String cep) {
    this.cep = cep;
}

public Double getLatitude() {
    return latitude;
}

public void setLatitude(Double latitude) {
    this.latitude = latitude;
}

public Double getLongitude() {
    return longitude;
}

public void setLongitude(Double longitude) {
    this.longitude = longitude;
}
```

}

Create user on firebase (this is my register actitivy)

```
private void criaUsuarioFirebase (String email, String senha){

        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, senha)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                            //Log.d("TagCerta", "createUserWithEmail:success");
                            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

                            empresa.salvar(); //writing values
                            Intent inicio = new Intent(CadastroPt2Activity.this, NavegationActivity.class);
                            String categoria = spinnerCategoria.getSelectedItem().toString();
                            inicio.putExtra("categoria", categoria);
                            startActivity(inicio);
                            finish();


                        } else {
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                            Log.w("TagErrada", "createUserWithEmail:failure", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(CadastroPt2Activity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }

                        // ...
                    }
                });
    }
```

this is my store.java where i save all values.

```
public class Empresa {

private String uid;
private String nomeEmpresa;
private String nomeProprietario;
private String telefone;
private String email;
private String categoria;
private String descricao;
private String idUsuario;
private String senha;
private String tempo;
private String taxa;
private String cpf;
private String cnpj;
private Double precoEntrega;
private Localizacao localizacao;
private String urlImagem;


public Empresa() {
}

public void salvar(){
    setUid(UsuarioFirebase.getUsuarioAtual().getUid());
    DatabaseReference database = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getFirebaseDatabase();
    DatabaseReference reference;
    if(getCpf().equals("") || getCpf().equals(null)) {
        setCpf(null);
        reference = database.child("empresa").child(getUid());
    }
    else{

        reference = database.child("empresa").child(getUid());
    }

    reference.setValue(this);

}

public String getUid() {
    return uid;
}

public void setUid(String uid) {
    this.uid = uid;
}

public String getCategoria() {
    return categoria;
}

public void setCategoria(String categoria) {
    this.categoria = categoria;
}

public Localizacao getLocalizacao() {
    return localizacao;
}

public void setLocalizacao(Localizacao localizacao) {
    this.localizacao = localizacao;
}


public  String getDescricao() {
    return  descricao;
}

public void setDescricao(){
    this.descricao =descricao;
}

public String getTaxa(){
    return taxa;
}

public void setTaxa(){
    this.taxa = taxa;
}


public String getTempo(){
    return tempo;
}

public void setTempo(String tempo){
    this.tempo = this.tempo;
}

public String getNomeEmpresa() {
    return nomeEmpresa;
}

public void setNomeEmpresa(String nomeEmpresa) {
    this.nomeEmpresa = nomeEmpresa;
}

public String getNomeProprietario() {
    return nomeProprietario;
}

public void setNomeProprietario(String nomeProprietario) {
    this.nomeProprietario = nomeProprietario;
}

public String getTelefone() {
    return telefone;
}

public void setTelefone(String telefone) {
    this.telefone = telefone;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

@Exclude
public String getSenha() {
    return senha;
}

public void setSenha(String senha) {
    this.senha = senha;
}

public String getCpf() {
    return cpf;
}

public void setCpf(String cpf) {
    this.cpf = cpf;
}

public String getCnpj() {
    return cnpj;
}

public void setCnpj(String cnpj) {
    this.cnpj = cnpj;
}



public String getUrlImagem() {
    return urlImagem;
}

public String getIdUsuario() {
    return idUsuario;
}

public void setIdUsuario(String idUsuario) {
    this.idUsuario = idUsuario;
}

public Double getPrecoEntrega() {
    return precoEntrega;
}

public void setPrecoEntrega(Double precoEntrega) {
    this.precoEntrega = precoEntrega;
}

public void setUrlImagem(String urlImagem) {
    this.urlImagem = urlImagem;
}
```

}

this is my json *Edited

```
 "empresa" : {
"7tQGfB7utBWZBtJM2XvuxMH57Sl1" : {
  "categoria" : "petshop",
  "cnpj" : "",
  "cpf" : "99999999999",
  "email" : "mauro@gmail.com",
  "localizacao" : {
    "bairro" : "Jardim Planalto de Viracopos",
    "cep" : "13056-016",
    "cidade" : "Brazil",
    "estado" : "São Paulo",
    "latitude" : -22.989735,
    "longitude" : -47.1418681,
    "numero" : "27",
    "rua" : "Rua Luzia Evangelista Eusébio"
  },
  "nomeEmpresa" : "mauro pet",
  "nomeProprietario" : "mauro",
  "pedidos" : {
    "-Lq7o5ykWNyGBcab6WkZ" : {
      "estado" : "Aguardando interação",
      "idPedido" : "-Lq7o5ykWNyGBcab6WkZ",
      "produto" : {
        "descricao" : "teste",
        "idProduto" : "-Lq7o5ykWNyGBcab6WkZ",
        "idUsuario" : "7tQGfB7utBWZBtJM2XvuxMH57Sl1",
        "nome" : "teste",
        "preco" : 10
      },
      "quantidade" : 1
    }
  },
  "telefone" : "+5519982674837",
  "uid" : "7tQGfB7utBWZBtJM2XvuxMH57Sl1"
},
```

Comment: wouldn't be good to put images anyway, you should put the code itself

Comment: which one is the code that is crashing? ConfirmarPedidos line 118

Comment: You've included pictures of the code and JSON tree in your question. Please **replace** them with the actual code and JSON as text. The JOSN you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in the overflow menu (⠇) of [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the code and JSON as text makes then searchable, allows us to easily use them to test with your actual code/data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: sorry, i edited now

Comment: yes is crashing on ConfirmarPedidos line 118

Comment: Please also add the content of your `Localizacao` class. Please also responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: ok, i add a localizacao class @AlexMamo

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the following error:

> Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.ezcompras.model.Lojas

Due the fact that you are using the following reference:

```
DatabaseReference lojaRef = mDatabase
        .child("empresa")
        .child(idLoja) //idStore
        .child("localizacao");
```

That points to a node that represents a it self a `Localizacao` object. Because you are looping through its children which are actually strings, you get that error. So if you want to get a single `Localizacao` object, there is no need to loop, you just can simply get the `Localizacao` object like this:

```
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Localizacao localizacao = dataSnapshot.getValue(Localizacao.class);
        Log.d(TAG, localizacao.getCidade());
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
lojaRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

And the result in the logcat will be:

```
Brazil
```

Comment: hmm, i undertand but i need to get a specific localizacao how i specific what child firebase return to me? @AlexMamo

Comment: What specific localizacao do you want to get?

Comment: i need to get a  "empresa {idLoja example :7tQGfB7utBWZ){Localizaco

Comment: I'm afraid I did not understand. Please add a screenshot and highlight on it the exact data that you want to get.

Comment: i post in top a image about a date who i whant do get and a JSON, if you whant i can post all JSON

Comment: I think it will be better to have a screenshot with a more detailed schema. But don't forget to **highlight** the data that you want to get.

Comment: hi sorry for my late, o post now in first image i whant what is in red( i dont know is correct speak like this)

Comment: Using my code, you can get that object. Have you even tried my code?